# Почему после выполнения onDataChange() объект становится null?

Tags: java, android, firebase, null

У меня есть массив `Users`, который я заполняю в методе `onDataChange()` в `ValueEventListener()`. Когда я проверял через логи переменные, `u.email` выводил правильное значение из `БД` `FireBase`.

Я записываю это значение в массив, и конструктора `ValueEventListener()` этот элемент массива почему-то становится равным `null` (проверил через логи), соответственно и ошибка `NullPointerException`.

Вот код:

```
static User[] r = new User[1];

static User getById(String id){
    DatabaseReference dbr = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
    ValueEventListener vel = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            for(DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()){
               User u = ds.getValue(User.class);
               Log.d("log", u.email);
               if(u.email == id)  
                   r[0] = u;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {}
    };
    dbr.addValueEventListener(vel);
    Log.d("log", r[0].email);
    return r[0];
}
```

Вот логи:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.teamfind, PID: 16075
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.String 
com.example.teamfind.User.email' on a null object reference
at com.example.teamfind.User.getById(User.java:54)
at com.example.teamfind.Project.getByString(Project.java:81)
at com.example.teamfind.ProjectsLoader$1.onDataChange(ProjectsLoader.java:28)
at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:75)
at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:63)
at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:55)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8031)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:620)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1011)
```

Comment: а он до момента записи вообще существует? вы уверенны что его получаете из FB?

Comment: Про асинхронность слышали? Колбэк `onDataChange()` выполняется после получения данных из базы, а метод `getById()` возвращает значение сразу. Вам нужно изменить логику работы с данными с императивной на реактивную. То есть вызывать код работы с объектом `User` из колбэка его получения.

Comment: Называть объекты `u`, `r` и так далее не стоит =).

Comment: @woesss "вызывать код работы с объектом User из колбэка его получения" - не совсем понял вас. Квинтессенцию проблемы понял - мой метод выполняется раньше, чем инициализируется список, но не совсем понял, как мне решить мою проблему. Расскажите, пожалуйста, подробнее, где мне нужно вызвать код, чтобы логику работы с данными можно было назвать реактивной